# Azure cloud service cannot read from web project's web.config

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

The config value is stored in the `Web.config`. When I build the web project, the `Web.config` gets copied to the build folder as `{ProjectName}.dll.config`. Running the web app locally works fine, the config value gets read without problem using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["{key}"];`.

When I build the cloud service however, the `{ProjectName}.dll.config` does not get copied to the `cspkg` file that I upload and run on Azure. I would expect it to be in `approot/bin`. However there is a `Web.config` in `approot`.

Running on Azure the app fails when trying to read from the app settings using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["{key}"];`.

I am aware of `CloudConfigurationManager` but I would like to avoid having to maintain the configuration in both, `Web.config` and the cloud `cscfg`.

Answer (score 0):

> The service configuration file specifies the number of role instances to deploy for each role in the service, the values of any configuration settings, and the thumbprints for any certificates associated with a role.

In Solution Explorer, select Properties>Development>Service Configuration and set the value as Cloud.

[image]

Then, set the web role's Service Configuration as **Cloud**.

[image]

In setting tab, **Add Setting** about connection string and what you want to store.

[image]

The following code illustrates an example of how to access a connection string. Replace the  placeholder with the appropriate value.

```
// Setup the connection to Azure Storage
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("<ConnectionStringName>"));
```

For more details about how to configure Azure Cloud service roles with Visual Studio, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-configure-roles-for-cloud-service).